# How make all programs close to the notification-area like rhythmbox does?

Tags: rhythmbox, notification-area

I say "close", not "minimise". I dont want minimise to tray like some programs do, I want to close to tray, like Rhythmbox does. When I close the window I want the program to remain running but be minimised to the notification-area.

Answer (score 8):

## [ALLTRAY](http://packages.ubuntu.com/alltray) [image: alltray]

AllTray is a program written for Unix-like systems to enable a user to dock any program (such as Evolution, Thunderbird, or a terminal program) into the system tray. This is mostly useful when one wants to have a program always running, but easy to put out of the way.

with [AllTray](https://launchpad.net/alltray), you can minimize any app to the system tray.